# Ajax Javascript Promise returns wrong value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a real issue with promises. The way the API works that I am using is that you first request a reportID, then you query the reportID to get your data.

My ajax code used to work just fine for this, until I tried to implement promises. Now it only responds with the reportID from the "get" query, but what I actually want returned is the data response from "return (result);".

I think this is to do with me using "return" in front of getReport at the top, but if I remove it it breaks my promise

> index2.html:16 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of
>   undefined
>       at index2.html:16

**index.html**

```
function firstFunction() {
  return getReport(2, 'queue', 'hour', '2018-09-09', '2018-09-10', 'pageviews', 'page', 's1390_5bbb443734ab6a764639ff37');
};
var test = firstFunction();
test.done(function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

**report.js**

```
function getReport(ref)
{

   return $.ajax({
        url: "report.php", 
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { 
            ref: ref
        },
        success: function(result){
           if (type == 'queue')
           {   
               getReport(result.reportID, 'get');
           }
           else if(result.error == "Bad Request") 
           {
           }
           else if(result.error == "report_not_ready") 
           {
           setTimeout(function(){
            getReport(ref, 'get');
            },1000);  
           }
           else
           {
           return (result);
           }
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: You are using success field as well as promise... This is not how we use promise. All the implementation in "success" field are to be called in "done" method

Comment: try something like this $.ajax().done(d => $.ajax(d.id)).done((finalData) => console.log(finalData))

Comment: @Jimmy why you're passing multiple arguments to `getReport()` when you use just the first one `ref`?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I cut them out to make the question more simple to understand